# How to include xelatex in a mamba environment?

Tags: python, conda, xelatex, mamba

Running a particular Python program within my environment tries to produce PDF output, which requires "xelatex". I tried adding "xelatex" to the environment creation command:

```
mamba create -n notebook_rapidsai_env ... python jupyter xelatex
```

but this produced the following error:

```
Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides requested xelatex
```

I have also tried "latex". The does not appear to be anything in the Mamba documentation about adding xelatex support. How is that done?

Comment: Do you have an environment.yml file? You can add dependencies there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding XeLaTeX to a mamba environment requires the use of conda to activate the environment and then for the installation of dependencies.

```
mamba create -n notebook_rapidsai_env 
conda activate notebook_rapidsai_env 
conda install -c conda-forge xelatex
```